# What is language-code for English (United States - International)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout

When in Powershell, I type:

```
Get-WinUserLanguageList
```

I only get 2 (of 3) from list:

```
en-US
en-GB
```

But doesn't show the item for "(United States-International)".

[image]

What is language code for it? `en-INTL` ??

Answer (score 2):

The following script arose from my older answers to alike questions on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A376602%20WinUserLanguageList) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3439404%20WinUserLanguageList).

```
Param ( [parameter(Mandatory=$False)] [int16]$Out = 0 )
$regBase = 'Registry::' + 
           'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts'
Function Get-Intl {
param( [string]$InputMethodTip )
    $auxlang, $auxKeyb = $InputMethodTip -split ':'
    $auxLangIn = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::
                    GetCultureInfo( [int]"0x$auxlang" ) # -band 0x3FF )
    $KbdLayout = Get-ItemProperty -Path (
                            Join-Path -Path $regBase -ChildPath $auxKeyb
                        ) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ( $KbdLayout.PsObject.Properties.Name -contains 'Layout Id' ) {
        ###           ↓                                           unclear!
        $LayoutId  = "f$($KbdLayout.'Layout Id'.Substring(1))"
        ###           ↑                                         incorrect!
    } else {
        $LayoutId  = $auxKeyb.Substring(4)
    }
    $HKL = "$LayoutId$auxlang"
    [psCustomObject]@{
        HKL            = $HKL
        InputMethodTip = $InputMethodTip
        Name           = $auxLangIn.Name
        # Autonym        = $WinUserLanguage.Autonym
        # DisplayName    = $auxLangIn.DisplayName
        KbdLayoutName  = $KbdLayout.'Layout Text'
    }
}

Switch ( ($Out % 3) )
{
0 {
    Write-Verbose '--- Get-WinUserLanguageList output:' -Verbose
    # $WinUserLanguageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
    # $LayoutsReal = 
    ForEach ( $WinUserLanguage in ( Get-WinUserLanguageList ) ) {
        $WinUserLanguage.InputMethodTips | ForEach-Object {
            Get-Intl -InputMethodTip $_
        }
    }
    # $LayoutsReal
    break
}
1 {
    Write-Verbose '=== HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT output:' -Verbose
    $regDefa = 'Registry::' + 
               'HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile'
    # HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup
    # $LayoutsHkuD = 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $regDefa -Force | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property |
            Where-Object { $_ -match ':' } | 
                ForEach-Object {
                    Get-Intl -InputMethodTip  $_
                }
    # $LayoutsHkuD #| Sort-Object -Property Nane
    break
}
4 {
    Write-Verbose '--- DISM.exe output:' -Verbose
    ## DISM.exe /Online /Get-Intl
    ## gives following values in the 'Active keyboard(s)' line:
    ## '0809:00000405, 0405:00000405, 0405:00020409, 0408:00010408, 0419:00020419, 041b:0000041b, 041f:0000041f, 041f:00000426, 0425:00000425, 0425:00010409, 0809:00000452'
    #
    ## but DISM.exe insists upon #requires -RunAsAdministrator
    ## hence, here are merely pasted&copied values:
    $DismActiveKeyboards = '0809:00000405, 0405:00000405, 0405:00020409, 0408:00010408, 0419:00020419, 041b:0000041b, 041f:0000041f, 041f:00000426, 0425:00000425, 0425:00010409, 0809:00000452' -split ', '
    # $LayoutsDism = 
    $DismActiveKeyboards | 
        ForEach-Object {
            Get-Intl -InputMethodTip  $_
        }
    # $LayoutsDism #| Sort-Object -Property Nane
    break
}
    default { Write-Verbose "$out = DISM.exe output isn't available as yet" -Verbose }
}
```

**Example**: `D:\PShell\tests\InputMethodTip.ps1`

> ```
> VERBOSE: --- Get-WinUserLanguageList output:
>
> HKL      InputMethodTip Name  KbdLayoutName              
> ---      -------------- ----  -------------              
> 04050809 0809:00000405  en-GB Czech                      
> 04520809 0809:00000452  en-GB United Kingdom Extended    
> 04050405 0405:00000405  cs-CZ Czech                      
> f0010405 0405:00020409  cs-CZ United States-International
> 04090405 0405:00000409  cs-CZ US                         
> f0020405 0405:00010409  cs-CZ United States-Dvorak       
> f0160408 0408:00010408  el-GR Greek (220)                
> f0330419 0419:00020419  ru-RU Russian - Mnemonic
> ```

The script merely shows information from `Get-WinUserLanguageList` in a tabular form expanding `LayoutName` better than confusing

```
if ( -not ("System.Windows.Forms.Form" -as [type]) ) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
}
[System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage]::InstalledInputLanguages | 
    ForEach-Object { '{0} 0x{1:x8} {2}' -f $_.Culture, 
                       ($_.Handle -band 0xffffffff), $_.LayoutName 
    }
```

> ```
> en-GB 0x04050809 Czech
> cs-CZ 0x04050405 Czech
> cs-CZ 0x04090405 US
> cs-CZ 0xf0020405 US
> cs-CZ 0xf0010405 US
> el-GR 0xf0160408 Greek (220)
> ru-RU 0xf0330419 Russian - Mnemonic
> en-GB 0x04520809 Czech
> ```

Answer (score -1):

United States-International is not a Language code, is a InputMethod.
So, if you want to add en-US(International) keyboard layout to a language, use something like this:

```
$actualKB = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$actualKB[0].InputMethodTips.Add('0409:00020409') > #Add en-US(International)
Set-WinUserLanguageList $actualKB -Force
Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip "0409:00000409" #set default keyboard en-US(International)
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-windefaultinputmethodoverride?view=windowsserver2022-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=windowsserver2022-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winuserlanguagelist?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: How does this differ from the answer from 3 years ago?